# Confusion with preg_match

Tags: php, file, preg-match

this is probably very easy question...
I don't really know how to use pattern search (`preg_match`) and I am faced with code which includes it...

```
if (preg_match('!http://.*?/photos/.*?/(\d+)!i', 'http:/example.com/sites/default/files/1301584398_file.jpg', $match)) {
    $id = $match[1];
    $info = $f->photos_getInfo($id);
    $sizes = $f->photos_getSizes($id);
    foreach($sizes as $size => $sizedata) {
        if ($size == "Large" || $size == "Original") {
            $source = $sizedata['source'];
            if (preg_match('/\.(jpg|jpeg)$/i', $source)) {
                $jpg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
            }
            if (preg_match('/\.png$/i', $source)) {
                $jpg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
            }
            if (preg_match('/\.gif$/i', $source)) {
                $jpg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

I am most confused by

```
preg_match('!http://.*?/photos/.*?/(\d+)!i', $url, $match)
```

What is this for? Since the input pattern have changed and I have no idea how it looked before it is a bit confusing... 
The other function are pretty clear. They are meant to get the extensions of files.

Comment: its looking for a file name in a directory where 2 deep a dir is called photos and the file name starts with a number

Comment: Dagon's right. Did you want this regular expression to specifically do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!http://.*?/photos/.*?/(\d+)!i` means a case insensitive match of `http://.*?/photos/.*?/(\d+)`, where the pattern delimiter used was `!`.

`http://.*?/photos/.*?/(\d+)` matches any url having `/photos/` in it, then something more, ending in `/` and some numbers.

`.*?` tries to match as little characters as possible, possible none at all. `\d+` tries to match as much numbers as possible, with a minimum of 1.

Answer (score 1):

[preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)() is a function used to do a regular expression match on a string, and store matches to an array.

The first parameter is a regular expression.  It's a special syntax used to define patterns for matching text.  I highly recommend the following link for learning regex syntax, as it's highly useful, although a bit cryptic at first and tricky to decipher.

[Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

In your pattern:

- `!`               - the regex delimiter 
                     (usually a regex uses `/`, but we need to use slashes literally in our pattern).
- `http://`   - a literal match of the string 'http://'
- `.*?`           - match any character (`.`), zero or more times (`*`), and be 'lazy' (`?`). 
                     (Lazy means: match the least possible num of chars while still satisfying
                     the whole pattern)
- `/photos/` - another literal string match
- `.*?`           - same pattern as explained above. (0 or more of any char, tell regex engine to be lazy)
- `/`               - A literal string match for forward slash '/'
- `( )`           - In regex, parentheses are a special character. 
                     Used to Create a group to reference later as $match[1].
- `(\d+)`       - Match one or more digits `\d+`, and create a group to contain the match.
- `i`               - A flag used to tell the regex engine to ignore case.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
preg_match('!http://.*?/photos/.*?/(\d+)!i', $url, $match)
```

searches for the `http://` string, followed by any character up to the first `/`, then `photos/`, then any other sequence of character up to another `/`, then a sequence of one or more digits which are recorded via backreference.

In other words, scan for http links whose second segment is `photos` and grab the numeric id at the end of the URL.